# inside oncreate method can't read the content of php file?

Tags: java, php, android

I created an android app. I try to get content from a PHP file. I wrote the logic in below `getCont()` method, but it doesn't work. It always returns null in Android. When I do the same with Java it returns the PHP content. How to solve this, so no exception is thrown.

```java
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String dbcont = getCont();
    tone = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    tone.setText("usean :-)"+dbcont);
}

public String getCont() {
    String mit = null;
    try {
        URL oracle = new URL("http://localhost/grace/conn.php");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(oracle.openStream()));
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String inputLine;             
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        }

        mit = sb.toString();
        System.out.println(mit);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return mit;
}
```

Comment: What exception is thrown? Please show the stack trace.

Comment: I would reference http://developer.android.com/training/basics/network-ops/connecting.html.  That should give you a step by step guide how to make network calls.

Comment: no exception will come very clean but It returns null value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're saying you're not getting an exception? You're opening a URL connection on the UI Thread.  This is restricted on android. I'm surprised the app isn't crashing.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html

You have to use a separate thread to perform network functions. Read this

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

You need to create a class that extends `ASyncTask`, then in the `doInBackground()` method, you can open the connection to fetch your PHP file.

You can then return the results which will be passed on to the `onPostExecute()` method. That will allow you to pass the data from the connection (i.e. the PHP file) back to your UI thread.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. To avoid headache with AsyncTask I would also recommend the Volley library, which removes a lot of boilerplate.

Comment: # Andrew Senner, Yes Its work like charm. Thanks to ALL

Comment: one more thing, use your IP address instead of localhost for example (http://192.168.1.5/grace/conn.php)